# Run SQL Agent Job from TFS

Tags: sql-server, tfs, .net-core, devops, tfs-2015

How do I run a SQL Agent Job from TFS Server? We are creating a data warehouse.

I have published a database schema with following

```
sqlpackage.exe /publish with publish profile.
```

Now I want to run a SQL Agent Job to Populate the Data Warehouse.
I do Not want to place the sql agent job in post deployment script.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 
    @job_name='TestPackage' 
    ,@server_name='TestServer1234'
```

[image]

Using SQL Server 2016 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Command Line Task and provide the commands to execute your provided TSQL script.

```
sqlcmd.exe -S servername -d Databasename -U username -p password -i inputScript.sql
```

Comment: Is there anyway to avoid the username and password? When I run sqlpackage.exe above, I am not required to input username or password

Comment: You can store you password in a variable or use Integrated Windows Authentication with the -E parameter (Service Account of the Build Agent will be used)